# How do I download folders through FTP in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, data-transfer, ftp

How do I download a whole folder through FTP in Terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mget` is the closest you can get with the included FTP binary. You have to mkdir and cd/lcd and then get all the files than match a pattern like `*`

The `prompt` toggle may come in handy.

FTP works within a directory, not on directories as containers of files. If you absolutely had to get the job done and ftp was the only tool you could use - you could cobble together an `expect` script to drive ftp for you.

Thankfully there are alternatives like `scp`|`rsync`|`wget` to get whole directories worth of files.

Comment: Ok...so the bottom line is that I can't download a whole folder at one time; I have to download the individual files, right?

Comment: Yup. Everyone wouldn't be showing wget, sftp, scp and rsync if ftp were up to the task.

Comment: Thanks...does SFTP allow folder downloading?

Comment: Oops (sorry) - no. sftp is the same syntax and limitations of ftp - just securing the connection using ssh instead of ftp authentication.

Comment: If you're bound to the FTP protocol you can use [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) to do a recursive download of a directory tree. Old school solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use curl

```
curl ftp://ftp.com/mp3/* --user login:password -o /myfolder/*
```

I think this is working, or file by file

```
curl ftp://ftp.com/mp3/mymusic.zip --user login:password -o mymusic.zip
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: OK, thank you very much, but is there a way via FTP to do this?

Comment: Awesome! I was unaware of curl's FTP proclivity. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah...neither was I. I'll probably use it more often.

Comment: first suggestion does not work.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion but getting this: `curl: (78) RETR response: 550`

Comment: `curl` absolutely cannot handle this. `wget` can.

Answer (score 4):

I had to download 22'000+ webcam pictures from my web server, which is a bit of a challenge for both the Finder and my FTP program CyberDuck.

So I did the following (based on @bmike's answer):

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/image-dump-myserver
ftp ftp://myuser@myserver.com
# enter password

# You're now in the ftp console (where the world is still okay)

# Set the local folder
lcd ~/Desktop/image-dump-myserver

# cd into the desired folder (`ls`, `pwd` etc. all work here)
cd /httpdocs/images

# Toggle the interactive mode
prompt

# Download the desired files (all the images in my case)
mget *.jpg
```

Then the files are being downloaded into the desired folder:

```
local: image1433509292_1582.jpg remote: image1433509292_1582.jpg  
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50001|)  
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for image1433509292_1582.jpg (63626 bytes)  
100% |***********************************| 63626        1.51 MiB/s    00:00 ETA  
226 Transfer complete  
63626 bytes received in 00:00 (0.98 MiB/s)  

local: image1427279963_0841.jpg remote: image1427279963_0841.jpg  
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50053|)  
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for image1427279963_0841.jpg (67194 bytes)  
100% |***********************************| 67194        1.64 MiB/s    00:00 ETA  
226 Transfer complete  
67194 bytes received in 00:00 (1.04 MiB/s) 

local: image1439798493_1783.jpg remote: image1439798493_1783.jpg  
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50357|)  
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for image1439798493_1783.jpg (48876 bytes)  
100% |***********************************| 48876        1.80 MiB/s    00:00 ETA  
226 Transfer complete  
48876 bytes received in 00:00 (996.81 KiB/s)  
....
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using

```
wget -r -l 10 --ftp-user='FTP_USER' --ftp-password='FTP_PASSWORD' \
    ftp://ftp.server.com/folder_to_download/*
```

Unfortunately `wget` doesn't support parallel downloads.

Answer (score 3):

Use `scp` [(documentation)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/scp.1.html) or `sftp` [(documentation)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sftp.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/sftp)

```
scp -r login@myserverip:/remote/directory/path/ mylocaldirectory
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. My question is: How do I download a folder via FTP in Terminal? In other words, what commands in FTP do I use to download a folder?

Comment: sftp is far superior to FTP +1

Comment: @bmike: yes, but older ftp servers may not support sftp.

Comment: Both links are dead :(

Answer (score 1):

follow this instruction :

type

```
ftp
```

then you are in ftp looking like

```
ftp>
```

then you open ip of server

```
ftp> open xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

then it will ask for username, you will provide

```
Name:(your ftp server): your_username
```

then it wil ask for password

```
Password:  your_password
```

then you should be logged in and see the ftp> shell again,
you can type "ls" to list all files and you can navigate like in inix with cd

when you found your filename you can download it with

```
ftp> get filename
```

et voila, the file will be downloaded to the directory you opened shell localy from

you cant download directorys, but you could navigate into your directory and download multiple e.g all files

Task: Download Multiple Files

You need to use mget command as follows to copy multiple files from the remote ftp server to the local system. You may be prompted for a yes/no (Y/N) answer before transferring each file (you can disable prompt by passing the -i option to ftp client). To download all files, enter:
ftp> mget *

information from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ftp-commands/
cheers

Comment: The ftp unix tool has been removed from OS X (in Sierra, I think?).

Answer (score 0):

```
lcd /dirtodownload 
prompt
mget *
```

From @Besi answer, was doing the job directory by directory, but I needed to download a large site via ftp.

Wget options works with a tradtional ftp server, (unlike scp or sftp)
Using the -m mirror option recursively downloaded all files.

```
wget -m --user=username --password='pswd' ftp://123.4.5.678
```